# Keras weighted_metrics does not include sample weights in calculation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am training a CNN model with a 2D tensor of shape (400,22) as both input and output. I am using categorical_crossentropy both as loss and metric. However the loss/metrics values are very different.

My model is somewhat like this:

**1. Using sample weights, and passing metrics with `metrics=` in `model.compile`.**

```py
# Imports
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import *
from tensorflow.keras import *
import numpy as np

# Build the model
X_input = Input(shape=(400,22))
X = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
           kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4), bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), 
           padding='same')(X_input)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', 
           kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4), bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), 
           padding='same')(X)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
y = Conv1D(filters=22, kernel_size=1, activation='softmax', 
           kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4), bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), 
           padding='same')(X)
model = Model(X_input, y, name='mymodel')


# Compile and train the model (with metrics=[])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
               metrics=[tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy])
Xtrain = np.random.rand(20,400,22)
ytrain = np.random.rand(20,400,22)
np.random.seed(0)
sample_weight = np.random.choice([0.01, 0.1, 1], size=20)
history = model.fit(x=Xtrain, y=ytrain, sample_weight=sample_weight, epochs=4)
```

```
Epoch 1/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 824us/step - loss: 10.2952 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.9296
Epoch 2/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 785us/step - loss: 10.2538 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.7858
Epoch 3/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 772us/step - loss: 10.2181 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.6719
Epoch 4/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 766us/step - loss: 10.1903 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.5797
```

From the results, it is evident that Keras is not using sample weights in the calculation of metrics, hence it is larger than the loss. If we change the sample weights to ones, we get the following:

**2. Sample weights = ones, passing metrics with `metrics=` in `model.compile.**

```py
# Compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
               metrics=[tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy])
Xtrain = np.random.rand(20,400,22)
ytrain = np.random.rand(20,400,22)
np.random.seed(0)
sample_weight = np.ones((20,))
history = model.fit(x=Xtrain, y=ytrain, sample_weight=sample_weight, epochs=4)
```

```
Epoch 1/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 789us/step - loss: 35.2659 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.2573
Epoch 2/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 792us/step - loss: 35.0647 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.0562
Epoch 3/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 778us/step - loss: 34.9301 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.9216
Epoch 4/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 736us/step - loss: 34.8076 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.7991
```

Now the metrics and loss are quite close with sample weights of ones. I understand that the loss is slightly larger than metrics due to the effects of dropout, regularization, and the fact that the metric is computed at the end of each epoch, whereas the loss is the average over the batches in the training.

***How can I get the metrics to include the sample weights??***

**3. UPDATED: using sample weights, and passing metrics with `weighted_metrics=` in `model.compile`.**

It was suggested that I used `weighted_metrics=[...]` instead of `metrics=[...]` in `model.compile`. However, Keras still does not include the sample weights in the evaluation of the metrics.

```py
# Compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
               weighted_metrics=[tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy])
Xtrain = np.random.rand(20,400,22)
ytrain = np.random.rand(20,400,22)
np.random.seed(0)
sample_weight = np.random.choice([0.01, 0.1, 1], size=20)
history = model.fit(x=Xtrain, y=ytrain, sample_weight=sample_weight, epochs=4)
```

```
Epoch 1/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 764us/step - loss: 10.2581 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.9224
Epoch 2/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 739us/step - loss: 10.2251 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.8100
Epoch 3/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 755us/step - loss: 10.1854 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.6747
Epoch 4/4
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 746us/step - loss: 10.1631 - categorical_crossentropy: 34.5990
```

***What can be done to ensure that the sample weights are evaluated in the metrics?***

Comment: What is the shape of `ytrain` ? And what kernel_size are you using for your `Conv1D` layers?

Comment: ytrain and Xtrain are of the same shape, (400,22). I'm using a kernel size of 2.

Comment: I have it in the `model.fit` function. Where would you want to have it updated?

Comment: How is `sample_weight` defined?

Comment: It is calculated as the inverse of the bin size to which the sample belongs. The entire data is first split into 10 bins, the frequency of each bin is evaluated, and each sample in a bin is assigned `max_bin_size / bin_size` as its sample weight.

Answer (score 3):

Keras does not automatically include sample weights in the evaluation of metrics. That's why there is a huge difference between the loss and the metrics.

If you'll like to include sample weights when evaluating metrics, pass them as `weighted_metrics` rather than metrics.

```py
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              weighted_metrics=[tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy]))
```

Comment: Have you checked this with your example? It doesn't give close or similar results too.

Comment: However, the difference in the results can be explained by dropout and regularization, which are applied in the loss but not in the metrics. Hence, as expected, the loss is slightly greater than the metrics.

Comment: Have you tried removing the dropout and regularizers? Probably not, because after removing it still doesn't give the close results. If you find close results (which was your initial question), then add a reproducible code sample.

Comment: Even after removing dropout and regularizers, there is still the effect of batches. The loss is computed as the average over all batches in a training epoch, whereas the metric is computed **only** at the end of the epoch. This difference in how losses and metrics are computed implies that they will **not** be equal. What matters is that they are not too far apart.

Comment: I think it still doesn't work, at least not for random `sample_weight`, it still gives a good difference which can never be explained with the facts you described. If it solves your problem, drop a reproducible code example for future reference.

Comment: You're right. Keras is still ignoring sample weights even when `weighted_metrics` is used.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, categorical cross-entropy is usually not used as a metric. Secondly, you are doing some type of seq2seq task, I hope you design the model with that intention.

Finally, in your setup, using `sample_weight` only works on the loss, it has no effect on the metrics or validation. There are other small bugs in your code too. Here is the fixed working code:

ref: [TF 2.3.0 training keras model using tf dataset with sample weights does not apply to metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380057/tf-2-3-0-training-keras-model-using-tf-dataset-with-sample-weights-does-not-appl) *(why `sample_weight` only works on loss)*

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras import *
import numpy as np

X_input = Input(shape=(400,22))
X = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4), bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), padding='same')(X_input)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='elu', kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4), bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), padding='same')(X)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
y = Conv1D(filters=22, kernel_size=1, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4), bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), padding='same')(X)

model = Model(X_input, y, name='mymodel')
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3), loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
metrics=[tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy])

Xtrain = np.random.rand(10,400,22)
ytrain = np.random.rand(10,400,22)

history = model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, sample_weight=np.ones(10), epochs=10)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 719ms/step - loss: 35.4521 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.4437
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 35.5138 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.5054
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 35.5984 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.5900
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 35.6617 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.6533
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 35.7807 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.7723
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 35.9045 - categorical_crossentropy: 35.8961
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: 36.0590 - categorical_crossentropy: 36.0505
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 36.2040 - categorical_crossentropy: 36.1956
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: 36.4169 - categorical_crossentropy: 36.4084
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 36.6622 - categorical_crossentropy: 36.6538
```

Here, if you use no `sample_weight` or 1 for each sample, you will get close/similar categorical cross-entropy.

Use `weighted_metrics` according to docs.

Comment: That's interesting! 

According to this link (https://keras.io/api/metrics/),

**"Much like loss functions, any callable with signature metric_fn(y_true, y_pred) that returns an array of losses (one of sample in the input batch) can be passed to compile() as a metric. Note that sample weighting is automatically supported for any such metric."**

I thought the sample weight will be automatically included in the metrics evaluation.

How can I ensure that sample weights are used in metrics?

Comment: I see that I'll need to pass the list of metrics as `weighted_metrics`, rather than 'metrics` in the `model.compile` function.

Comment: Read the reference answer.